# Hochschild complex differential

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, algebra

For a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $A$ with basis $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ (structure of algebra encoded by structural constants $\{c_{ij}^k\}_{i,j,k=1}^n$ such that $e_ie_j = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{ij}^k e_k$), the differential of Hochschild complex is the map $T(A) \to T(A)$ where $T(A)=\oplus_{i=0}^\infty A^{\otimes i}$ is a tensor algebra. The map is defined on irreducible tensors such that:

$$d(a_0 \otimes ... \otimes a_n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^n a_0 \otimes ... \otimes a_i a_{i+1} \otimes ... \otimes a_n$$ $$d(a_0) = 0, d(\operatorname{const})=0$$

I have a couple questions.

*Question 1*

Let's say I have a set $S = \{e_1,e_2\}$ and some complex numbers $\{c_{ij}^k\}_{i,j,k=1}^2$ such that $e_ie_j = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{ij}^k e_k$. How can I code this? To be a little more concrete, I want to insert something in:

```
S = {a,b};
c111=0; c112=0; c211=0; c212=0; c221=0; c222=0; c121=2; c122=3;
(*INSERT SOMETHING*)
(a+3*b)**b== 2*a + 3*b
```

Replace "(*INSERT SOMETHING*)" such that the last equation is true.

*Question 2*

I want to code the Hochschild differential in such a framework. So, i want to realize a function hochschildD in such a way, that:

```
hochschildD[TensorProduct[a,b,a]] == TensorProduct[a**b,a] - TensorProduct[a,b**a]
```

will be true. Hope for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that `a` and `b` are vectors, and `c` is a rank 3 tensor:

```
$Assumptions = (a|b) ∈ Vectors[{2}] && c ∈ Arrays[{2, 2, 2}];
```

Then, in your notation:

```
a_ ** b_ := TensorContract[TensorProduct[c, a, b], {{1, 4}, {2, 5}}]
```

For your example we have:

```
Block[{c = SparseArray[{{1, 2, 1}->2, {1, 2, 2}->3}, {2,2,2}]},
    ({1,0} + 3 {0,1}) ** {0,1} //Normal
]
```

> {2, 3}

We can incorporate this definition of `a ** b` directly into a definition for `hochSchildD`:

```
tensorQ[t_] := TensorRank[t] > 0

iD[t_?tensorQ, i_] := TensorTranspose[
    TensorContract[TensorProduct[c, t], {{1, i+3}, {2, i+4}}],
    Cycles[{RotateLeft @ Range[i]}]
]

hochSchildD[t_?tensorQ] := Sum[
    (-1)^(n+1) iD[t, n],
    {n, TensorRank[t] - 1}
]
```

Then:

```
hochSchildD[TensorProduct[a, b, a]]

(*
TensorContract[
  c\[TensorProduct]a\[TensorProduct]b\[TensorProduct]a, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}}] - 
 TensorTranspose[
  TensorContract[
   c\[TensorProduct]a\[TensorProduct]b\[TensorProduct]a, {{1, 5}, {2, 
     6}}], {2, 1}]
*)
```

For better visualization, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Let's check your condition:

```
TensorReduce[
    hochSchildD[TensorProduct[a, b, a]] == TensorProduct[a**b, a] - TensorProduct[a, b**a]
]
```

> True

Using your previous metric we could also obtain:

```
Block[{c = SparseArray[{{1,2,1}->2, {1,2,2}->3}, {2,2,2}], a={1,0}, b={0,1}},
    hochSchildD @ TensorProduct[a, b, a] //Normal
]
```

> {{2, 0}, {3, 0}}